# (Windows) How to make auto-update function for plugin?

Tags: windows, dll, plugins, auto-update

I have a question. I'm writing a plugin (.dll) for an application (.exe). And I want to code auto-update function for my plugin but I catched an issue, it could not apply. Because my plugin has loaded while application is running, in run-time it cannot replace. It just apply until application has exited. So, how can I do it?

This is my code: http://codepad.org/4a22ccMa

Thanks!

Comment: Improve your question by showing some code, and telling more about your program and your system.

Comment: You should put relevant parts of your code inside the question (with four spaces at least before each source code line), not give a link outside.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(this answers the original question, which has been edited to something completely different)</sup>

It depends upon the operating system (which I guess might be Windows, since you speak of DLLs; on Linux you have [shared objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries) (in [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)) with a different semantics). Read Levine's book [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/).

You might read more about [Dynamic Software Updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating). This is a entire research subject with a lot of scientific literature about it. Read e.g. the paper about [*Kitsune:  Efficient, General-purpose Dynamic Software Updating for C*](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jfoster/papers/toplas-kitsune.pdf) (at least to understand several issues in your question).

On Linux, you could [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) the old `.so` and [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) the new one (and probably `dlclose` the older one, but you should do that later, when no active call frame on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) points into the old plugin), and my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) example shows that you practically can `dlopen` a big lot (more than a million in practice) of shared objects.

On Windows (which I don't know) you probably need to [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) the *new version* of the plugin in a *different* file path. Probably, restarting your program after a plugin update should make things much easier.

<sup>(if you can afford that, switching to Linux might be very helpful, because I guess that it is much easier)</sup>

Notice that in some languages (and some of their implementations) replacing some code is much easier than in C or C++ on Windows. I guess that in [CLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) ([managed code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code), e.g. in C#) or in a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) (e.g. in Java, Scala, Clojure) it should be easier. And in [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) (at least with [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)) it is quite easy (in particular since Common Lisp is an [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) language).

Take care of the [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), i.e. of the call stack. You'll understand that your question (also related to orthogonal [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29) & [application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing)) is much deeper and more difficult than you have imagined. And upgrading classes and their instances is also very difficult.

Comment: I'm sorry but I want to do it on Windows. On Windows it could not be replaced while it loaded in running process.
I known an API here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
This API has a flag MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT, it will replace until system is restarted. But this isn't a good idea. I want to replace it when process restart. :(

Comment: Perhaps you want to do something which might be impossible on Windows. Did you try to load a *different* file path for the DLL? You probably need to ask a much better and more focused question and show some source code in it. Don't forget to tag your question correctly (if it is Windows specific, tag is with `Windows`)

Comment: I think it not an impossible thing. I saw some application can.
It just can contain in the Plugins folder. So I can not change its path.

Comment: As I told you, I don't know Windows and never used it (but I am coding since 1974). So I cannot help you. You should ask a much more specific question and show some code (in that other question). Tag it with Windows if it is specific to Windows. But you should read the paper about *Kitsune*, it is very readable and brings very interesting issues.

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks for your answer and I apologize for asking a question is not clear.

Comment: You should ask another question and show several dozens of source code in it. Even with the edit, your question remains unclear.